# Error Convert String to DateTime

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,'17/05/2015 22:15:00',103)
```

output:

```
2015-05-17 22:15:00.000
```

I want include 2 column is Date+Time

Example: Colunm Date and Time

```
**Date**   **Time**

17/05/2015  22:15:00
```

but Error Query

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,[Date]+' '+[Time],103) FROM LPTables
```

Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the time portion to the date portion:

```
SELECT DATEADD(ms, DATEDIFF(ms, '00:00:00', [Time]), CONVERT(DATETIME, [Date]))
FROM LPTables
```

This will give you accuracy to the millisecond.

Answer (score 0):

Just enclose your columns with `()`.

```
 SELECT CONVERT(datetime,([Date]+' '+[Time]),103) FROM LPTables
 WHERE ISNULL([Date],'')!='' AND ISNULL([Time],'')!=''
```

Sample :

[image]

Comment: yes,but change Column Name It error


help me please.

Comment: There may be other string values in your columns other than date and time..may be a blanck space.. thats why you are getting this error..

Comment: I just included a where condition to handle the Null and blank space .. try with that..